# Pass additional parameter to callback function

Tags: javascript

I have a pretty simple function that is reading a file with HTML 5 FileReader:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
var currentFileType = file.type;
reader.onloadend = readCompleted;
reader.onerror = fail;

reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

and the readCompleted callback function looks like this:

```
    function readCompleted(evt) {
        if (evt.target.readyState != FileReader.DONE) {
            return;
        }

        // The binary data is the result.
        var requestData = evt.target.result;

        // SOME MORE CODE HERE
    }
```

Thing is that 'evt' parameter is passed by default. How can I pass one additional parameter to this callback function in order to have currentFileType variable available? I want this function signature to look like this:  `function readCompleted(evt, fileType) {//code here}` and pass somehow currentFileType to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign a different function to `reader.onloadend`.

```
reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
    readCompleted(evt, currentFileType);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind an argument to the function before assigning it to `onloadend`.

For example:

```
var a = function() { console.log(arguments); }
var b = a.bind(null, 123)
b('abc') // -> [123, "abc"]
```

In your case, it would be:

```
reader.onloadend = readCompleted.bind(null, file.type);
```

and `readCompleted` should have the following signature:

```
function readCompleted(fileType, evt) { ... }
```

Comment: In 15 years of development, I've never known that the default parameters are still passed, but at the end of the bind! You're my hero.

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this,

```
var reader = new FileReader();
var currentFileType = file.type;
reader.onloadend = function(evt){
    readCompleted(evt,currentFileType);
};
reader.onerror = fail;
```

The readCompleted will look like this,

```
function readCompleted(evt,ft) { //code... }
```